# Counting the number of SPECIFIC/CERTAIN values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, count

I am not trying to count the number of values in the dictionary

Here's my code:

```
def use_favcolors(fav_color):
    count = 0
    for green in fav_color:
        if green == fav_color:
            count += 1
    print count

def main():
    use_favcolors({"John": "green", "Bobby": "blue", "PapaSanta": "yellow"})
main()
```

Why does this print 0? Since there is a green in the dictionary, shouldn't it print 1?

Comment: First, you're doing `for green in fav_color:`, but then comparing `if green == fav_color`. That can never be true—you're asking if each individual color is equal to the whole collection of colors. (And the fact that you use a variable named `green` for individual color, whether they're green or not, is probably confusing you.)

Comment: Second, `fav_color` is a dict. When you loop over a dict with `for x in d:`, you're looping over its _keys_, which are `"John"`, `"Bobby"`, etc. You want `fav_color.values()`.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Dumb mistake. W/o the quotation marks, the green is a variable

Comment: Right. So can you figure it out yourself from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def use_favcolors(fav_color):
    count = 0
    for i in fav_color:
         if fav_color[i] == "green":
         count += 1
    print(count)

def main():
    use_favcolors({"John": "green", "Bobby": "blue", "PapaSanta": "yellow"})
main()
```

Your if statement logic did not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate the values of your dictionary. Currently, you iterate the keys in the dictionary, without ever accessing values.

Note that `for i in fav_color` is an idiomatic way of iterating keys in Python.

The Pythonic way to iterate values is to use `dict.values`:

```
def use_favcolors(fav_color):
    count = 0
    for color in fav_color.values():
        if color == 'green':
            count += 1
    print count
```

Another way you can implement your logic is to use `sum` with a generator expression. This works because `True == 1`, since Boolean is a subclass of `int`.

```
d = {"John": "green", "Bobby": "blue", "PapaSanta": "yellow"}

res = sum(i=='green' for i in d.values())  # 1
```